# How to add in jenkins file block to catch certain error?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

im building jenkins file, and i have noticed that sometimes,stage passed however mvn test throw error in the end due to some test failure,

what i want to do is to add try and catch block to detect if error message : 
"[ERROR] There are test failures." appears the stage will be failed and build will fail as well

here is part of my code

```
    stage('Testing') {
  steps {
        bat(script: 'mvn test', label: 'Testing process')
  }
}
```

How to add in jenkins file block to catch certain error ?

Comment: You need to get whatever `mvn test` is doing to exit with a non-0 status when tests fail. Jenkins will then fail the whole pipeline automatically. Right now it seems that `mvn test` is exiting as if all is ok, even if the tests fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use try/catch/finally Syntax.
Head over to Jenkinsfile Docs and search for "try":

[Jenkinsfile Docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/)

Syntax is like:

```
try {
       // do some magic
} catch (error) {
       // catch Error
} finally {
       // do finally
}
```

Comment: thanks andre for you answer, but i was wondering if there is way to detect certain error such  "[ERROR] There are test failures."
if it occurs the stage will fail

Comment: As far as i know Jenkinsfiles are similar to Groovy. Maybe try something like this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_exception_handling.htm

But there is also an open issue for this Question: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36816